# Term to describe “revenge through sexual intercourse”?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, interpersonal-relations, pejorative-language

What term can be used to describe someone who,
to take revenge on or extract payback for (perceived) past wrongs
done them by their (unfaithful) romantic partner,
goes off and has casual sex with someone other than their customary partner?

Comment: What are the circumstances in which this would constitute taking revenge?

Comment: @Neil Getting back at a cheating boy-/girlfriend by cheating on them?

Comment: Well, there's an eye for an eye, so this one could be an eye for a ***

Comment: ***Revenge sex*** is a term with some currency (though it has slightly different meanings depending on whom you ask), but it refers to the act, rather than the person. The transparently derived _revenge sexer_ yields exactly **one** (relevant) hit on Google, so it’s probably safe to say it is not usable.

Comment: call is *sex feud* akin to *blood feud*

Comment: [Possibly related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it was the original reference to "with the opposite sex", and no mention of partner that made me think it might have been something else.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would say that this person has his/her priorities mixed up. Then I would say that person is [vengeful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vengeful):

> Desiring vengeance; indicating or proceeding from a desire for revenge.

[vindictive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vindictive) and *spiteful* work as well:

> Disposed to seek revenge; revengeful; marked by or resulting from a desire to hurt; spiteful.

Other similar words are [*resentful*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resentful): full of or marked by resentment or indignant ill will; "resentful at the way he was treated".

Or, they might not be angry at all, but maliciously calculating.

There are also bitter, hurt, wounded, angry, offended, put out, jealous, pissed, incensed, grudging, aggrieved, indignant, pissed off, irate, miffed, embittered, unforgiving, and peeved, but not all of them apply equally.

I would not differentiate on th basis of gender. What's good for the goose is good for the gander.

Comment: I agree with your last sentence (the inclusion of “with the opposite sex” seemed very arbitrary and unnecessary to me when I read the question); but all the words you mention fall short of the mark in that they do not imply sexual relations in any way. That I do feel is an integral part of the question. (Whether there are any words that _don’t_ fall short of the mark, though, is a different matter. I can’t come up with any.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’ve edited the question to be both more descriptive and less restrictive in its biases of sexual chirality.

Answer (score 1):

Talionic:  adj. -pertaining to revenge in kind; retributive; **like for like**;  pertaining to **revenge in kind**

&

[**Talionic**](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/460514/talionic): Of or pertaining to the law of talion, or to the rendering of like for like.

Comment: "retaliative" is another adjective that is etymologically related.

Answer (score 0):

What word can be used to describe someone that takes revenge or [payback](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/payback) for **wrong done in the past** through having a **casual** sexual intercourse with the opposite sex?

Consider [sexually retaliatory](http://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/indiana/inndce/4:2007cv00066/52491/32).

> "**Sexual Retaliation against the Opposite Gender**: The pattern of [sexual retaliation](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=wySxsaFrRLEC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=%22sexual+retaliation%22&source=bl&ots=9WjmeK2X6n&sig=Cf_eOemlBsuCzLPDHAHjqKkQtig&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=wM-JU_mVEIOV0AX1rIHIBg&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22sexual%20retaliation%22&f=false) against the opposite gender involves a predominantly hostile reaction to breakup, in which the main purpose of sex is to hurt and humiliate any new lover."
>
> [retaliate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retaliate): to return like for like; esp. to get revenge.

Alternate terms are [*sexual revenge*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sexual+vengeance%2Csexual+retaliation%2Csexual+revenge%2Crevenge+sex&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csexual%20vengeance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csexual%20retaliation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csexual%20revenge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crevenge%20sex%3B%2Cc0) and [*sexually revengeful*](http://repository.asu.edu/attachments/56418/content/Murray_asu_0010N_10385.pdf), *sexual vengeance*, and *revenge sex*.

Comment: I hate it when an answer gets repeated downvotes but no comments as to what the downvoters would see improved.

Comment: +1- good answer, and also to undo your downvote.

Comment: I like the term but I understood it to be used as a  power play over a subordinate, and not a revenge f*ck

Comment: This sounds like "you're pissed at [gender] so you treat your next [gender]friend badly," which is almost the opposite of what's being asked for. The behavior described is that you've been cheated on (or otherwise mistreated by a partner), so you're going to go have a lot of sex with other people to make your partner jealous"